# ResearchKit RELEASE build error: module "ResearchKit" not found

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, researchkit

When running the project in DEBUG the project builds with ResearchKit fine. When trying to release a TestFlight build, or when building in RELEASE the Xcode project can not find the module "ResearchKit". It seems, something in Xcode (the build system) is preventing the Project module from accessing the ResearchKit module in Release config.

Followed the steps written in the ResearchKit README for adding the framework to my project, and cloned the main repo into my projects folder.

```
git clone https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit.git
```

I thought maybe the problem was specific to my project, so I made a HelloWorld project and ran into the same issue.

**ErrorMessage-**

[image: errorMessage]

Thought maybe the lack of the bridge header file/path was the problem, but after adding a bridge-header file the project was still unable to find the ResearchKit module.